# What's the difference in comparative use between ～ + の様に / みたい / が如く, etc.?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This question has been on my mind since I've watched SEGA's announcement the other day about Yakuza's second installment getting a remake. The original title of the game is [龍]{りゅう}が[如]{ごと}く, meaning "like a dragon." I've been wondering, how would the sense of the phrase change if in the place of ～が[如]{ごと}く I'd insert の[様]{よう}に, making it [龍]{りゅう}の[様]{よう}に? Now that I think about it, would it mean "having the appearance of a dragon"? Also, how would the sense of the phrase be different with other ways to express similarity?

Comment: It just sounds archaic.

Answer (score 2):

I would say みたい is a little different because that's more along the lines of 'looks like', 'seems like', giving an opinion based on observation.

のように is more descriptive, emphasizing actual commonality with the object of comparison.

To be honest I've never consciously come across 如く before in daily Japanese life, and I've lived in japan for 1 plus years and am working in a Japanese company as a kind of translator(Bridge SE) - so I'd agree with the person above that its probably just an archaic version of  のように - to make stuff like game titles sound a bit cooler

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve downvotes, I think.

Comment: Don't understand why that got downvoted, interested in hearing why though (and obviously being corrected if I've got something factually wrong) if anyone would like to do that

Comment: I think the other form of みたい should be mentioned. I got downvoted for forgetting that on a different account answering a similar question :/